# Add a new fileld in the Magento admin section manage category page

Tags: magento

I am looking to add a text input box in admin section of ***Magento in the Magento manage categories page***.Is it possible to do that? If yes, I would like to know how.

Comment: It is possible, but not an easy task as you probably already know. Try some tutorial.

Comment: can you please suggest me some tutorial which can help me on this,because i haven't come across one which can help me on this

Comment: You could try this one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/286643/, its not exactly does what you want to do, but could be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

We can add attribute using code

other option is you can install below module :

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/custom-attributes-4340.html

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating text box in the adminhtml template file. Most probably this would be:

magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/category/edit/form.phtml

But you also need to create new column in database to save the data. You can do that by writing a simple extension of your own and with a SQL upgrade script.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to add an attribute within Manage Categories section in Magento admin.

To add an attribute you need to run a SQL file using a custom module.

Here is the code snippet which you can execute -

```
<?php 
   $installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
   $installer->startSetup();
   $installer->removeAttribute('catalog_category', 'attribute_code');

   $installer->addAttribute('catalog_category', 'attribute_code',  array(
     'group'    => 'General Information',
     'type'     => 'text',
     'label'    => 'Attribute Label',
     'input'    => 'text',
     'global'   => Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute::SCOPE_STORE,
     'visible'           => true,
     'required'          => false,
     'user_defined'      => false,
     'default'           => '',
     'visible_on_front' => true,
     'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
 'position' => 4, 
 'sort_order' => 4,
));


 $installer->endSetup();

?>
```

I hope you're looking for the above code.